# Cant pass data JQuery $.ajax to ashx handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, ashx

This is a part of my AJAX code:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.ashx?method=LoadCities",
        data: "{state_id:'" + state_id + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
.
.
.
```

and this is a part of my ASHX handler code:

```
public class ajax : IHttpHandler {

    public void ProcessRequest (HttpContext context) {

        context.Response.ContentType = "application/json;charset=utf-8";

        string method = context.Request["method"];
        if (method == "LoadCities")
        {
            object ss = context.Request.Form["state_id"];
            context.Response.Write(LoadCities(ss));
        }
    }
```

I can't get **"state_id"** and it is always `null`
How can I get **"state_id"**

Comment: can you inspect the ajax request in the chrome developer tools to see if the form data is correctly included? You should see it appear under the "Network" tab

Comment: @rdans my ajax method doesn't have any problem. but I can't pass a parameter and get its value in ASHX.

Comment: How did you determine that the problem isn't on the ajax request side? did you already check it?

Comment: @rdans yes I check it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass it as query string,

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "ajax.ashx?method=LoadCities&state_id=" + state_id,
    contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
```

.
.
.

and get your state_id in your .ashx handler,

```
string lsStateId = System.Convert.ToString(context.Request.QueryString["state_id"]);
```

Comment: @Dxterity What is difference between `context.Request["state_id"]` and `context.Request.QueryString["state_id"]`

Comment: context.Request is the collection of all posted data (QueryStrings, Input Controls,..etc) from your form and context.Request.QueryString is the collection of only query string variables.